# In Swift 3, how do I get UnsafeRawPointer from Data?

Tags: swift, swift3

According to the documentation of Data in Swift 3, there is an initializer that I can use to create a Data from UnsafeRawPointer. What I need actually is the opposite. I have a Data, and I want to create a UnsafeRawPointer that points to the bytes of the Data. Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
1. let data = <from some where>
2. let unsafePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)
3. unsafePointer.initialize(to: 0, count: data.count) // is this necessary?
4. data.copyBytes(to: unsafePointer, count: data.count)
5. let unsafeRawPointer = unsafePointer.deinitialize() // this is of the type UnsafeMutalbleRawPointer, and I can use it where UnsafeRawPointer is needed.
```

I verified that this code works in Xcode Playground. The code even works without the line number 3. I'm not sure what is the difference with or without the line. Anyway, my question is, am I doing right for what I want? Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`withUnsafeBytes()` gives you a (typed) pointer to the bytes,
this can be converted to a raw pointer:

```
let data = <Data from somewhere>
data.withUnsafeBytes { (u8Ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
    let rawPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(u8Ptr)
    // ... use `rawPtr` ...
}
```

The pointer is only valid during the lifetime of the call to the
closure.

Alternatively, you can bridge to `NSData` and access the raw bytes:

```
let nsData = data as NSData
let rawPtr = nsData.bytes
```

Now the pointer is valid in the same scope where `nsData` is valid.

As of **Swift 5** it is

```
let data = <Data from somewhere>
data.withUnsafeBytes { rawBufferPointer in
    let rawPtr = rawBufferPointer.baseAddress!
    // ... use `rawPtr` ...
}
```

because the closure argument is now a `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`.

Comment: The solutions look better and cleaner than mine. And the second one is quite straight forward too.

Comment: It seems that the `withUnsafeBytes` is the right one for me. It looks safer than the NSData solution

Comment: `withUnsafeBytes` seems limited.  What if I wanted several pointers to perform operations on all of them?

Comment: @ryantxr: `Data` is a collection an you can access its bytes directly via subscripting, so  in many cases you don't need withUnsafeBytes at all, only if you want to pass a pointer to a C function, or do some "reinterpret" casting. *If* you have to do that for several Data objects simultaneously then you would need a nested `withUnsafeBytes`.

Comment: The second solution to cast to `NSData` and use `.bytes` works well

Comment: The casting option is great. Just use the NSData constructor (Swift 3) instead of casting directly, this way -> ```NSData(data: Data)```

Comment: Weirdness in Swift 4 for me: `UnsafeRawPointer(ptr)` works, but `UnsafeRawPointer.init(ptr)` does not.

Comment: @MartinR “the pointer is valid in the same scope where nsData is valid”. So if my `NSData` is an instance property of an Swift class, then is the `NSData.bytes` value valid for as long as an instance of that class exists? What exactly is meant by “scope” here’s?

Comment: @algal: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410616-bytes: *"For an immutable data object, the returned pointer is valid until the data object is deallocated. For a mutable data object, the returned pointer is valid until the data object is deallocated or the data is mutated."*

Comment: @MartinR thanks, good find! It seems like all the pure Swift API which provides an unsafe pointer tells you it’s valid only for a closure’s scope, and only this NSData API offers pointers promised to have a longer life.

Answer (score 9):

Check [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data).

We cannot find a method or property which retrieves `UnsafeRawPointer` from a `Data`.

So, for alternative:
[func withUnsafeBytes((UnsafePointer) -> ResultType)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes)

You can write something like this:

```
let data: Data = <initialize it as you like>

data.withUnsafeBytes {(uint8Ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
    let rawPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(uint8Ptr)
    //`rawPtr` (and `uint8Ptr`) is guaranteed to be valid in this closure
    //...
    //You have no need manage `rawPtr`.
}
```

(Oh, this is the same as the first half of Martin R's answer.)

---

But if you want to keep your `UnsafeRawPointer` valid for a longer period than in a closure, you need to make a copy of the content of the `Data`:

For example:

```
let uint8Ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)
uint8Ptr.initialize(from: data) //<-copying the data
//You need to keep `uint8Ptr` and `data.count` for future management
let uint8PtrCount = data.count
//You can convert it to `UnsafeRawPointer`
let rawPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(uint8Ptr)
//Use `rawPtr` while `uint8Ptr` is valid
//...
//Deinitialize and deallocate the region
uint8Ptr.deinitialize(count: uint8PtrCount)
uint8Ptr.deallocate(capacity: uint8PtrCount)
```

(You can get `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` as a return value of `deinitialize(count:)`, but the region is in an **uninitialized** state, so you should not access the region.)

Comment: Thanks for two solutions. Both of them look better than mine.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 5:

```
'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
```

A possible solution is:

```
buffer.withUnsafeBytes{ (bufferRawBufferPointer) -> Void in

    let bufferPointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = bufferRawBufferPointer.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    let rawPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(bufferPointer)
    //USE THE rawPtr

}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea to use UnsafePointer<Int8> instead of UnsafePointer<UInt8> ?

it is possible with depreceated version of the solution

Comment: I think it's possible with deprecated solutions. However, I think that the 'trick' for you will be to replace UInt8 for Int8. My solution says to 'bufferPointer' to assume as UInt8 type. Let me know if it works. @EmreTufekci

Comment: Yes it's working, i'm using deprecated version already, just wondered is it works with "non deprecated" version. But afau it will not. Thank you @Reimond.